# How to model a calendar application?

Tags: calendar

I need to create an application that will have a calendar component that will support pretty much all the event types that you can create in Outlook and/or iCal and will store it in a relational database.

I was wondering if there is a standard calendar model out there or should I just hack it myself. I looked at iCalendar, but that's more communication oriented. I'm more interested in storing events in a database.

Or if anyone knows any good open source database backed calendar that I can take a look at and learn.

Thanks!

Comment: What platform are you developing for?

Comment: Java. But a database schema or the object model in any other language can be useful too.

Comment: As you've noted the `iCalendar` and `vCalendar` specs are built for this (a lot of the communication stuff is optional).  Nice broad compatibility too.  I'm not sure you need to start in these formats, but setup your tables with them in mind.